# Google Satellite Imagery Offset in QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, imagery, basemap, xyz-tiles

I am using Google Satellite imagery as a base map to capture the vector data in QGIS 3.2.2 for past couple of months. Yesterday i noticed that the google imagery has offset issue in some locations where i have already worked on. Since that location was already captured with reference to the google imagery but now it shows major offset(approx 70 meters) between the vector and google imagery. This location is belongs to California, USA. (-119.17907,34.23393).

I have attached the screen shot of the vector location which was captured with reference to the Google imagery(before imagery updates) and this location almost matching with bing imagery but it showing major offset while using recent Google imagery as a base map. I hope this explains well about this issue.[image]

I also attached screen shot from the Google Earth Pro and its almost lined up with the vector data as similar to bing imagery.[image]

Does google updated their imagery on these locations, if yes then how its possible they update imagery with major offset issue?
Does anyone can let me know what is the issue for this and how it will be resolved. Please help me on this.

Comment: No. Typically, that kind of difference is caused by trying to render the project to a CRS other than EPSG: 3857. Whether to digitize or render, use EPSG: 3857 for your layers and the project, the tiles can not be reprojected on the fly to another system. Then, if you wish, you can export the vector layers to another CRS.

Comment: Hi, The issues are in some locations (i found in california) and i believe all other locations are matched perfectly with imagery. If i check with that location using bing imagery then the vector data is almost matched perfectly.

Comment: Honestly, I do not think there's been a change in google images. In any case, it would be necessary to consult them. Disadvantages with displacements of digitalizations made over their images yes, they usually happen and can be due to many reasons. My recommendation is that you edit your question with the most detailed information possible of the procedures so that someone can reproduce the problem, screenshots of your visualizations, and even files with sample data so they can be verified.

Comment: I have updated the problem with screen shot, hope this helps to understand better.

Comment: I have attached one more screen shot of the Google Earth Pro and its properly lined up with vector data as similar to bing imagery. The only issues is, there is a major offset while using the Google Satellite Imagery as base map in QGIS.

Comment: How are you adding the Google Satellite Imagery in QGIS?

Comment: I am adding Google Satellite imagery in QGIS using this link "http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}" in XYZ Tiles option

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I also tried with QGIS and came here... there is a slight shift between Bing and Google imagery with OSM vectors.
Google: https://imgur.com/a/EexvMQv
Bing: https://imgur.com/E96OHfE

Comment: @LasithNiroshan, Hi. You can try loading the basemaps from QuickMapServices plugin to see if the problem is in the way of the xyz tiles are being called. If the difference persists, seems to me a problem at Google or Bing side georeferencing their imagery.