# QGIS 3: ALKIS vs Google Satellite arange Layer congruently

Tags: qgis-3, google

ist possible to move the google layer by offset to fit the (correct positioned) alkis layer? (Alkis: UTM Zone 32N)

I know I can change the projection, but I tried some without success.

My Project KBS/CRS is EPSG:25832.

I read some similar threads but none of some helped.

Regards

Edit: Image added

[image]

PS: I load google with this link "https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}" as "X Y Z Tiles" out of the browser-list.

Comment: Could you add an image which shows the offset you want to correct?

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310586/google-satellite-imagery-offset-in-qgis

Comment: I think not because - as far as i unterstood - are the most given answer in this thread "KBS/CRS"-issues. And there is no solution.